# go reflect getting a method on an embedded type

Tags: go, reflection

I'm working on a go module which is descending down through a hierarchy of types and using reflect. No worries about "sleighting" go's efficiency by using reflect, this is just for part of the initialization – it will never affect on-going operations.

I'm trying to get a method from a type embedded in a type a few calls down in methods. So what I mean by types in types and methods in methods is shown here: https://play.golang.org/p/p1nhHxJe2e2

The line I am trying to get to work is `m := vField.MethodByName("Validate")` to get access to the method `func (tz *TZConfig) Validate(...)`

Comment: Yes, you can get the Validate method in otherStuff.  See  https://play.golang.org/p/yGbMIVHHdZM.   Please post a [mcve].

Comment: It's late where I am but I'm going to have to look into why that's not working for me because that is very obvious code (and of course I have tried it) and I'm not getting what you would expect. I'm betting on the culprit being that it is late and me being over tired with a lot of hours into this but I'll give proper feedback after daylight (can't say tomorrow because daylight is the same day).

Comment: A guess would be your method has pointer receiver yet you use a non-pointer value which won't have that method.

Comment: @user5429087 *"Instead I got the methods of the reflect type."* sounds to me like you're grabbing the reflect.Type/Value of a reflect.Type/Value, i.e. doing something to the effect of `reflect.ValueOf(reflect.ValueOf(c))` or `reflect.TypeOf(reflect.ValueOf(c))` or some other incorrect combination.

Comment: I've updated the title as I think I was a bit inaccurate, updated my description and created functionally equivalent code by stripping my code down to what will minimally show the problem and made sure it would run in go's playground.

Comment: `m := vField.Addr().MethodByName(`Validate`)`

Answer (score 0):

```
m := vField.Addr().Addr().MethodByName(`Validate`)
```